# paypal error code 15005

Tags: drupal, paypal, ubercart

I'm using ubercart paypal module as a mean for credit card transaction and it's doing grate job for me. But in some of the order detail i found this type of message in admin comment box -

First : for same transaction

```
Authorize and capture immediately failed.
Error: 15005: This transaction cannot be processed.
Address: Nothing matched; transaction declined
CVV2: Match
```

Secondly : for same transaction

```
Authorize and capture immediately
Success: 100.00 USD
Address: Nothing matched; transaction declined
CVV2: Match
```

I wants to know that error code: 15005 going to hurt my client badly?

what does it mean? -
1] Address: nothing matched, transaction declined

2] Authorize and capture immediately failed

Any suggestion or advice on this issue will gonna be helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Address: nothing matched, transaction declined` means that the address details provided by the payer did not match those of the cardholder. It's a security check performed by pretty much every online payment facility these days.

According to the [Paypal API Error Codes page](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes) error 15005 means:

> The transaction was declined by the issuing bank, not PayPal. The merchant should attempt another card.

Comment: I does know the meaning of error: 15005. But i wanted to know does this going to cause badly to our client? secondly if address not matched, even than customer completed the transaction successfully. How i can halt the transaction at the time of address validation failure. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by 'cause badly to our client'. If you mean will it reflect badly on you to your client then I guess that would depend on the individual, Paypal will tell them their payment has failed as they go through the transaction; how they interpret that with regards to your business is up to them. You can change your acceptance/fraud settings inside your Paypal account so I'd imagine you can set it to fail if the address verification fails.

Comment: Thanks for your commenting. I was little worry after seeing these kind of notification in my log entries. I'm going to check my paypal account security setting.

Comment: Thank Clive, the key was in paypal risk management link under profile tab where i can prevent and apply the setting for address checking and according to that halt the transaction